# How to loop and collect MultiInput values?

Tags: sapui5

I am using [`sap.m.MultiInput`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.MultiInput). How to send that data to the SAP Backend?

I tried using a loop:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < oLenght; i++) {
    var oData = this.getView().byId("myMultiInputControl").getTokens()[i].getKey();
}
```

But `oData` is holding always a new value. How to hold the data?

Comment: The question is unclear or somewhat too broad. But I see that you could already find the solution here https://answers.sap.com/questions/744009/how-to-get-multiinput-value-in-ui5.html
Would be great if you could post the solution here as well, not only to close this question but also to clarify the issue and the desired outcome for other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a  delimiter for example ("/" character) between the keys of the multinput and send the data to the backend  System :

```
if(oMultiInputElement.tokens.length > 1) {
    var dataToSend = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < oMultiInputElement.tokens.length; i++) {
        dataToSend = oFilterData.tokens[i].key + "/" + dataToSend;

        }
} else {
        dataToSend  = oMultiInputElement.tokens[0].key;

}
```

Comment: This is potentially dangerous, e.g. if the keys also contain '/' characters. You would really better use an appropriate data structure, such as an array. Then you even can get rid of the if/else:

`var dataToSend = []; ...; dataToSend.push(oFilterData.tokens[i].key);`